# How to form php array in the way I want?

Tags: php

The result for the below code is:

(0) 20
(1) 100
(0) 22
(1) 300

All I want is, to be able to address each value by the index, for instance:
In order to call the value 20 and 22 in the above list..$array[0] while to access 100 and 300 $array[1].

But when I access this way, it only shows the first digit for each value.

Example when I access $array[0]; result is:
(0) 2
(1) 1
(0) 2
(1) 3

My Code:

```
$size = sizeof($this->sub_rate);

        for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
        {
          foreach($this->sub_rate as $key=>$value)
          {

              foreach($value[$i] as $k=>$v)
              {

                     echo "<br/>(".$key.") ";
                      echo $v;




              }

          }
        }
```

Comment: can you show the results of `var_dump($this->sub_rate)`

Comment: @CodeGodie, it's shown above in the post

Comment: Array Keys must be unique, so you will not be able to access 2 values, by calling one key.  This is probably why you are having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the way you are building your arrays are not correct. if you can structure them better it would be very efficient for you since you want them paired. However if you cannot, then work with what you already have. Iterate over your current array to come up with an array that matches the index. Like this:

```
$arrs= array(
    array(
        array(20),
        array(22),
        array(null)
    ),
    array(
        array(100),
        array(300),
        array(null)
    )
);

$final = [];
foreach($arrs as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $k => $vals){
        if(!isset($final[$k])){
            $final[$k] = [];    
        }
        $final[$k][] = $vals[0];
    }
}
var_dump($final);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 300
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Now you can access the values needed by iterating over your `$final` or by just accessing directly like `$final[0][1]`

Hope this helps.